# How can I sign my debug apk with my release keystore in a multi-flavor project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, code-signing

I've got a product with 2 flavors (`prod` and `beta`) and I'm trying to sign my debug builds with my release keystore when I click run from android studio. I've defined a release and debug signing config (they're the same) and pointed both release and debug buildTypes to their respective signingConfigs but when I click run with the prodDebug variant selected, I get the following error:

> **Error**: The apk for your currently selected variant (XXXXXX-prod-debug-unsigned.apk) is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant (prod-debug).

Here's the relevant part of my build.gradle:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("xxxxxx.keystore")
            keyAlias "MyAlias"
            storePassword System.getenv("KSTOREPWD")
            keyPassword System.getenv("KEYPWD")
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file("xxxxxx.keystore")
            keyAlias "MyAlias"
            storePassword System.getenv("KSTOREPWD")
            keyPassword System.getenv("KEYPWD")
        }
        productFlavors.all { flavor ->
            flavor.signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        ~unrelated stuff~    
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles xxxxxxxx
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            ~unrelated stuff~
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        prod {
            ~unrelated stuff~
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Anyone know how to configure this? I've tried specifying the signingConfig in the flavor block as well and that didn't work either